# Ansible callback plugin: how to get a task name with variables in it expanded?

Tags: ansible

I have a play below that contains a task with a name that has a variable in it.

```
hosts:        localhost
connection:   local
vars:
  a_variable: test
tasks:
  - name:     this is a task to echo {{ a_variable }}
    shell:    echo {{ a_variable }}
```

When this is run on the command line, the stdout shows the task name with variable resolved/expanded to its value which is `this is a task to echo test`

However, when I try to access the task name in the callback plugin using the properties task.name or result._task.name, the name returned is `this is a task to echo {{ a_variable }}` where the variable is not expanded.

How can I get the task name as it is printed on stdout with the variable expanded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templated task name is only available inside `v2_playbook_on_task_start`.

If you want to use templated name in other methods, you should create plugin-wide list/dict, populate tasks' names during `v2_playbook_on_task_start` and fetch it later, when needed.

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use `task._uuid` as reference (see [profile_tasks](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.3/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py) plugin as example.